# Performance of NUMERIC type with high precisions and scales in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am storing cryptocurrency transaction balances in `NUMERIC` column. As cryptocurrency values vary in somewhat extreme ranges compared to traditional currency, I am using `NUMERIC(60,20)` type to capture all uses cases. As this feel little bit extreme, I am curious

- What are the performance (CPU) penalties of increasing NUMERIC column precision and scale
- What are the storage cost penalties of increasing NUMERIC column precision and scale

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The declared scale and precision of a `NUMERIC` column serve as a constraint on your inserted values, but they do not directly affect storage requirements; `1::NUMERIC(1,0)`, `1::NUMERIC(99,98)` and `1::NUMERIC` all have identical underlying representations. With this in mind, your best option might be to use an unconstrained `NUMERIC` column, and cast your values to a suitable scale/precision on a currency-by-currency basis.

`NUMERIC` values are stored as variable-length arrays of base-10,000 digits, each represented by a 16-bit integer, so the storage cost is 2 bytes per 4 decimal digits, plus a 6-byte header for each value. The fractional and integer portions are stored separately, so `11` consumes 8 bytes, while `1.1` requires 10. You can check the storage requirements for a given value using e.g. `SELECT pg_column_size(1.1::NUMERIC)`.

As for the CPU overhead, I would expect that the cost of most operations scales linearly with the number of digits. However, this is generally dwarfed by the I/O cost of fetching the value in the first place, so it's likely a non-issue. You'd have to try your queries on your own hardware to know for sure.

Comment: A truly beautiful answer! Thank you.

Comment: if I understand your explanation, the performance is a function of the numbers stored in the column, with the declared precision having little or no effect ... or would you say no effect whatsoever (compared to an unrestricted numeric type)?

Comment: @philwalk: Right, every value tracks its own precision and scale, and holds its own list of significant digits, so the column definition isn't a factor in the I/O or computation costs. That said, adding a constraint can certainly have an effect, as values are implicitly cast on the way in. If digits are rounded off, the value (and the costs) will shrink accordingly. And while increasing the scale doesn't actually mean storing any more trailing zeroes, it can still have an impact (e.g. functions like `sqrt()` are evaluated up to the precision of their inputs).

Comment: @Nick Barnes - thanks, I'm considering using postgresql NUMERIC without any constraints, to avoid periodically having to loosen the constraints as wider data arrives.   I realize it's not portable, but it avoids that type of maintenance work.

Comment: @philwalk: Ok, well as long as you cast all of your values to e.g. `NUMERIC(x,y)` on the way in, then it should perform identically to a `NUMERIC(x,y)` column. Make sure you do cast them, though, as the "default" number of decimal places can blow out unexpectedly. For example, division runs to at least 20 decimal places, and scales add during multiplication, so `scale((1.0/3)*(1.0/3))` is 40 (!).